# symfony2 database host is localhost

Tags: php, symfony

Here is my parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 192.168.1.7
    database_port: null
    database_name: kpb
    database_user: kpb_user
```

here is `echo $this->container->getParameter('database_host')` - from controller

```
192.168.1.7
```

here is stack trace -

```
2. at PDO ->__construct ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kpb;charset=UTF8;', 'kochampo_user', '
```

here is ...

```
echo __FILE__;
        var_dump($params);
        die();


vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.phparray(8) { ["driver"]=> string(9) "pdo_mysql" ["dbname"]=> string(3) "kpb" ["user"]=> string(8) "kpb_user" ["password"]=> string(12) "****" ["charset"]=> string(4) "UTF8" ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["port"]=> NULL ["driverOptions"]=> array(0) { } } 



grep -r "localhost" app/config/ 

return null
```

cache is cleare by `cache:clear` and i delete cache directory manually (database name change immediately) .

so how to change database host? why always is `localhost`?

Comment: What is in your config.yml file? I think your config.yml doesn't use parameter `database_host` in db configuration.

Comment: Try to clear your APC cache

Comment: yes i dont have host in config :) - i dont know who to remove it  i add  host:     "%database_host%" and now work

Comment: Ok. I can answer to your question and you will mark as right answer or you can deleter your question to not confuse other people

Answer (score 0):

You need to have next strings in your `config.yml` to make your db connection use host from parameters bag:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host:     "%database_host%"
```